# Create Docker image when application remote installs

Tags: docker, websphere, dockerfile, centos7

I have an application which comprises three servers, one component on each.

- Server1 = Component A
- Server2 = Component B
- Server3 = Component C

When you start the install on Server1, it *forces* an installation of Component B on Server2 and Component C on Server3, in addition to installing Component A on Server1.

If I were to start the installation on Server2, it likewise would install the other components on the respective servers.

It also means there must be running 'remote' servers, as it connects to these remote servers via SSH to copy the files and install them. Oh and it also refuses to install the application on a node if it detects it's already there.

It's just how it works to make it 'easier' for inexperienced folk, but harder to containerise. The vendor knows and maybe it'll change in the future, but this is how it is for now.

I'm trying to work out strategies to create separate images for each Component. A few thoughts:

1. Run the install on each Server and just create the images that way. It'd mean I'd need to orchestrate the starting **fresh** *remote* containers when I build the image for each Component.
2. Start 3x **fresh** containers, run the install on any of them then use docker commit to create the images. Would work but I don't like it makes it impossible to codify all container steps.
3. Maybe multi-stage Dockerfile? I'm not really sure about this.
4. Something else?

Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control over this installer system — it *requires* three hosts and makes remote connections as part of the installation process to the other two — then it will be difficult to impossible to turn it into Docker images, and the application vendor will be in a much better position to provide that for you.

If you know that the installation *only* installs software into specific places then in principle you could run the installation once, make tar files of `/opt/theapp` on each of the three systems, and then write minimal Dockerfiles that `ADD` the tar file content to each of three images.  Even then, though, you expect that the installer does some configuration for you (the host names of the three systems seems likely, for example) and you’d have to recreate this as a startup-time entrypoint script or something similar.

Rather than using Docker, you might be better off using a virtual-machine system or your favorite cloud provider, running the installer, and creating three system-level images that you can redeploy later.  If Docker is *really* a requirement then working with the vendor is going to be the best approach.

Comment: Yes that’s the other approach we may have to go with.. tar up directories, as we know where it installs. The VM images is “not supported” by the vendor. The vendor has images already, but only for POC scenarios.. but they support production containers if we roll our own.